# PHP imap_open for Microsoft Outlook from Basic Authentication to Modern Authentication

Tags: php, outlook, basic-authentication, imap-open

We are using imap_open() PHP function to connect and read outgoing and incoming emails (to,from,subject and time) and record them on our custom built CMS for recording emails sent and received by our clients.

Problem is Microsoft is shifting to Modern Authentication and imap_open() with outlook.office365.com will not work anymore.

I need step by step procedure to enable Modern Authentication and use imap_open() or other function to connect to mailboxes.

Looking for help!

Thank you.

Comment: Look at last User Contributed Notes of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php. It's seems it's not possible anymore. PHP-IMAP is a good alternative and works fine with XOAUTH2 : https://www.php-imap.com/

Comment: @svgta is there any other API we can use in PHP to read the emails using Modern Auth (OAuth2.0) ?